# How to get invisible border size for window resize on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10

I have an application that aligns other apps windows into grid. The problem is invisible border size. I can get that border by using API calls `GetWindowRect` and `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS`

But this doesn't work if the window is hidden. How can I get the size of that border for the hidden window or perhaps from the system?